# java aws client exception. Unable to execute http request: timeout waiting for connection from pool?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-lex, amazon-polly

I'm using the java aws sdk for polly and lex service.  Once in a blue moon, I get this error message and my services stop working.
This is from my brower console:

```
{data: 
error: 'Internal Server Error',
exception: 'com.amazonaws.SdkClientException',
message: 'Unable to execute http request: timeout waiting for connection from pool'
}
```

Comment: did you try to google this exception? Maybe this here can help you? : https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/269

Comment: Please check region settings